# Activeadmin gem installation error in Rails 4.0.0 app

Tags: installation, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

When I am doing bundle install after adding activeadmin to my gemfile I am getting following errors.

Resolving deltas: 100% (11082/11082), done.
    fatal: ambiguous argument 'rails4': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
    Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
   'git  [...] -- [...]'
    Git error: command `git rev-parse rails4` in directory
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/cache/bundler/git/active_admin-    d67faab65e9b74efbc8efb4a777a851e9f78b2ca
    has failed.
    If this error persists you could try removing the cache directory
   '/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/cache/bundler/git/active_admin-   d67faab65e9b74efbc8efb4a777a851e9f78b2ca'

And my Gemfile is as follows:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby "2.0.0"

gem 'rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails', '3.0.4'
gem 'turbolinks', '1.3.0'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'
gem 'devise', '3.0.1'
gem 'cancan', '1.6.10'
gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~>4.0.0'
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
gem 'pg_search', "~> 0.7.0"
gem 'carrierwave', "~>0.9.0"
gem 'simple_form', :git => 'git://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form.git'
gem 'bootstrap-sass',
git: 'git://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass.git',
branch: '3'
gem 'rmagick'
gem 'mini_magick'
gem 'fog'
gem 'carrierwave_direct'
gem 'sidekiq'
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'gregbell/active_admin', branch: 'rails4'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you only need the following, get rid of the branch "..."

```
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'gregbell/active_admin'
```

Comment: but how can you specify the branch you want?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is on following line

```
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'gregbell/active_admin', branch: 'rails4'
```

so read the instruction on https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin